# how does prototype differ from oop

Tags: javascript, c++, oop, prototype

When I first learned about javascript I thought it follow a similar pattern in c++ where class are like objects and you can use them the way want. But 
being the idiot I am thought javascript was the same thing. Then I realized javascript follows a prototype model.

Oddly enough for some reason I could not find this answer anywhere in stack overflow. But I was wonder how does a prototype model differ from say like a normal OOP model.

Side question. How would I change my thought flow from a classic oop model to a prototype model.